# SF Sending wrong welcome email

Tags: community, email-template, customer-portal

This is a very frustrating situation and I am not able to find any standard solution for this.

Our customer has one existing customer portal, which they are not using anymore, but it exists in production.

As part of their innovation program, they have created a new customer community and everything is working well. However when a new user is being setup for the community, Salesforce is still sending wrong email template, which was configured for portal.

Things I have checked so far:

- Email templates under community are setup properly
- Profile enabled for community is of correct type
- There are no profiles enabled for previous portal

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not very familiar with portals, however, do you see the template under Settings>Communication Templates>Email Templates? I believe they have a checkbox to disable them ("available for use")

Comment: I did that. So even you update new email templates to existing portal (Email templates are required fields) , it doesn't resolve the community merge field. This is so stupid of community.

Comment: The new community is a lightning costumer service one?

Comment: Yeah that's correct.

Comment: under community management, where you have Administration>Emails and then Email Templates,  how is that configured?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, it is configured as per the new templates.

Comment: And, are your users receiving 2 emails one form the old community with login creds, and then one from the new one with the link towards it?